# Why is Stack Overflow refusing to post my question?

Tags: support, quality-filter

This is my question: it is complaining about tags

> This post does not meet our quality standards.

I tried sequelize.js and node.js... no success...

this is really annoying

here is my question:

> Is it possible to pass a condition in the include array of a findAll
>   query?
>
> example: I have UsersModel, PostsModel, and UserVotesModel
>
> so users can vote on posts
>
> for the logged in user I want to query posts and include only the vote
>   for the current user.. I am not able to do this using Sequelize's
>   include param,,, Sequelize joins posts and UserVotes on postId, but
>   for this specific query I want to join on both postId and UserId
>
> any ideas?

Comment: Try using proper punctuation and capitalization. Multiple periods and commas are almost never necessary. And sentences start with a capital letter.

Comment: @Bart thanks, it worked!